# Classification of singularities - $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I have to classify the singularity at the origin of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{\sin z}$. How do I get this answer without passing through the Laurent serie directly . Is anyone could help me at this point?

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying by $z$:
$$ z f(z) = 1 + \frac{1}{\operatorname{sinc} z}, z \neq 0
$$
$\operatorname{sinc} 0 = 1$ and hence the above function has a removable singularity at $0$, so $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

@Henricus W. provides a fine solution.

The Laurent series is not so bad:
$$
 f(z) = 
 \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{\sin z} = 
 \frac{2}{z} + \frac{z}{6} + \frac{7z^{3}}{360} + \mathcal{O}\left( z^{5} \right)
$$

The benign behavior of the singularity is evidenced the conformal map below. $\Re (f)$ in blue, $\Im (f)$ in red.

[image: conformal map]